# How to clear or replace props which passed to root navigator

Tags: react-native, navigator

In my scenaria, I wanna passed 'token' to home view from login view through navigator and it works.

Unfortunately, when I exit login and navigate to login view, the params which once be passed to root navigator cannot be cleared or replaced.I had tried resetTo, but it not works.

So if I switch user, the token will not be changed in root navigator.
Of course, if I use push or initialize a new navigator, it will change 'token'.but I don't wanna do that. because, first, I'm not sure if I initialize a navigator, whether the old one was destroyed, if not ,it will waste memory, in my opinion.second, I don't wanna do extra useless works(if params can be changed in root navigator,the child can retrieve params from it without pass again)

so anyone could resolve it ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by myself
Not directly, but use build-in solution from navigator.
In initialRoute, I passed token to it , and in renderScene taken route.token for specified component.
After I logout from index page to login page, I passed token to push method , and then the token which in  Navigator tag was changed, and certainly it was passed to Index page.
So my new value is passed successfully,hope helps somebody~